# How to make a WinToUSB boot partition secure-boot proof

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi

I recently made my bootable usb stick using WinToUSB (win10 home / MBR for BIOS and UEFI) and, when I go to another computer to boot on it, I normally launch windows (from computer hard drive), press SHIFT and restart button, choose select boot device and Samsung partition 1. The problem is that if secure boot is activated in the host BIOS, it will boot on the internal hard drive. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what "safe boot" is.  I know what Secure Boot is, and I suspect that is what you actually meant to say, but I am not positive of that assessment.  If you use Advanced Startup are you able to change your EFI boot priority?  Please take the time, to edit your question, instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to boot from a USB drive while Secure Boot is enabled, but some pretty
strict conditions are involved.

The USB drive must use a FAT32 partition, the system must attempt to boot from the
USB in UEFI mode (which it always will if Secure Boot is enabled),
and the USB drive must contain a bootloader that is actually trusted by Secure Boot.

On Windows, Windows 8 and newer use trusted bootloaders, as do newer versions of
some Linux distributions.

I have found no information on the bootloader used by WinToUSB.
But judging by your experience, it is not acceptable when Secure Boot is activated.

Comment: So do there is a way to make WinToUSB bootloader secure boot acceptable?

Comment: Most motherboards allow only Microsoft keys as trusted, which means that WinToUSB must ask Microsoft to sign their bootloader. This process includes code audit by Microsoft and more. Most developers find it too difficult, and evidently WinToUSB didn't do it.